# How to load page with JS dependencies using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use [node-request](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-request) to make http calls and [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to traverse the DOM.

The problem I am having is that when content of a page is loaded via Javascript, then request and jsdom won't be able to get the page with the content already loaded.

Here is an example that you can try:

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

request({ uri:'http://koesbong.com/clients/self/sandbox/nodejs-test/' }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Error when contacting google.com')
  }

  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'
    ]
  }, function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    // jQuery is now loaded on the jsdom window created from 'agent.body'
    console.log($('p').text());
  });
});
```

If you load http://koesbong.com/clients/self/sandbox/nodejs-test/ in your browser, you will see "testing" on the page, which was appended using jquery on document.ready. But on the script above, the console.log won't show anything.

What can I do to make the script also get the page content?